# How to include an animated pdf

Tags: graphics, animate

I'd like to include a PDF generated with the animate package as a figure in a large document. The document compiles without any errors. Yet, the animation is not included. Can animated PDFs not be handled by pdfLaTeX?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{animated.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

"animated.pdf" is an arbitrary PDF, generated with \animategraphics, for example [animated.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw96duby31zdh67/animated.pdf?dl=0).

Also inclusion with the pdfpages package results in a blank page.
Am I missing something or how can I include such a file in a document? Or do I always need to generate the animation in the actual document?

Comment: The animations most likely relies on embedded javascript. But there the PDF is treated as a purely graphical element, so I assume that  meta data including any javascript are stripped away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current state of available TeX engines, such as `pdftex` and `luatex`, this is not yet possible. A number of document-level PDF objects and structures would have to be extracted from the PDF containing the animation and to be merged with those of the receiving PDF.

The same problem already exists for much simpler PDFs that just contain internal hyperlinks. Even this problem has been addressed only recently and is still at an experimental stage. See package [newpax](https://ctan.org/pkg/newpax).

Thus, for now, the `animate`-related TeX code has again to be inserted into the new document to reproduce the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was hoping that I could simply use two versions (animated, plain figure) for a digital and a print version, respectively, via includegraphics. Since it's only one figure, I guess I'll simply hardcode a newcommand in the pre-amble depending on whether the print option is used.